# Start CherryPy with different request_queue_size and timeout

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy application that I start with:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(None, "/", config=conf) 
cherrypy.quickstart(None, config=conf)
```

I recently introduced a page to the application that takes a considerable time to load (10 to 15 seconds in some cases) and started seeing random failures on the production server under moderate load.  I suspect this may be due to too many requests getting queued when several users request these long-running pages.

I'd like to experiment with allowing more requests to queue up.  I discovered that the built-in server has a request_queue_size setting that may control what I want.  However, I can't figure out how to change this setting using `cherrypy.quickstart`.

Comment: You don't need to call tree.mount before quickstart

Comment: Thanks, made that change as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in your `conf` dictionary:

```
conf = {'server.socket_queue_size': 10, ...}
```

Or you can programmatically change it:

```
cherrypy.server.socket_queue_size = 10
```

Using the dictionary is the better approach.

> In CherryPy 3, you use configuration (files or dicts) to set attributes directly on the engine, server, request, response, and log objects. So the best way to know the full range of what’s available in the config file is to simply import those objects and see what help(obj) tells you.

From [CherryPy v3.2.0 documentation » Tutorial and Concepts » Configuration](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/config.html)